# Gatsby navigate returns an array while passing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

My problem is when I pass to Gatsby's `navigate` function some account value to its state, in the `GoogleSingIn` component it shows as array. I want to print this value and I don't really know how to do it

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class GoogleSignIn extends Component {
  constructor({ location }) {
    super({ location })
    console.log(location.state)
  }
  render() {
    return <></>
  }
}

export default GoogleSignIn
```

and `Register` component

```
handleGoogle = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(result => {
        const token = result.credential.accessToken
        const user = result.user
        navigate("/google-sign-in", { state: user.displayName })
      })
...
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: yes, everything is clear

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 4):

In a class component, state passed to `navigate` can be accessed in `this.props.location.state`

```
// index.js
import React from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <>
    <form
      onSubmit={event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        navigate("/page-2", {
          state: { foo: "bar" },
        })
      }}
    >
      <input type="submit" />{" "}
    </form>
  </>
)

export default IndexPage
```

---

```
// page-2.js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

class SecondPage extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.state)
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Hi from the second page</h1>
        <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default SecondPage
```

#Note:

Be sure to pass an object to state:

`navigate("/google-sign-in", { state: {user: 'jackowsky'} })`

instead of just a string:

`navigate("/google-sign-in", { state: 'jackowsky' })`

otherwise it looks like the string will get transformed into an object that you don't want:

`Object {0: "j", 1: "a", 2: "c", 3: "k", 4: "o"…}`

[image: Edit blazing-shape-3gy5o]